# Log without HttpContext in ElmahCore

Tags: asp.net-core, elmah, elmahcore

I'm using [ElmahCore](https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore) in an ASP.net Core applicaiton,

in the docs I can see you can log manually using an extension method for the HttpContext, but I can't find anywhere how to log an error manually without having the HttpContext (from a background worker for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call
`ElmahExtensions.RaiseError(ex);`

(found it in the issues
https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore/issues/113 )

Comment: this helps me on ElmahCore, thanks.